# C++ Can not resize a 2d vector

Tags: c++

I have a problem with resize method from the vector library from c++.

I am trying to return my temp matrix, but it is not printed. It stucks after my resize.

This is my entire matrix class:

```
class Matrix {
  /*private:
    int rows;
    int cols;
    std::vector< std::vector<double> > data;*/

  public:
    int rows;
    int cols;
    std::vector <std::vector<double> > data;

    Matrix(int r,int c) {
      rows = r;
      cols = c;

      Serial.println(rows);
      Serial.println(cols);

      //data.resize(rows);
      Serial.print("hi");
      Serial.println(rows);
      Serial.println(cols);
      data.resize(rows, std::vector<double>(cols, 0.00));
      /*for (int n = 0; n < rows; ++n) {
        Serial.print(n);
        data[n].resize(cols, 0.0);
      }*/
      Serial.print("ho");

      show();

      /*for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
          data[i][j] = 0.0;
        }
      }*/
    }

    void show() {
      for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
          Serial.print(data[i][j], 4);
          Serial.print(" "); 
        }
        Serial.print("\n");
      }
      Serial.println("\n");
    }

void increase(float value) {
      for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
          data[i][j] += value;
        }
      }
    }

    int getRows() {return rows;}
    int getCols() {return cols;}
    int getSize() {return data.size()};

    static Matrix multiply(Matrix a, Matrix b) {
      a.show();
      b.show();
      int tempRows = a.getRows();
      int tempCols = b.getCols();

      Matrix temp = Matrix(tempRows, tempCols);
      Serial.println("load");
      temp.show();
      /*
      for (int i = 0; i < a.getRows(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < b.getCols(); j++) {
          int sum = 0;
          for (int k = 0; k < a.getRows(); k++) {
            sum += a.data[i][k] * b.data[k][j];
          }
          temp.data[i][j] = sum;
        }
      }*/
      return temp;
    }

};
```

here is what I run:

```
Matrix a(3, 5);
  Matrix b(5, 4);
  a.increase(4);
  b.increase(2);
  //a.add(b);
  Matrix x = Matrix::multiply(a, b);
  x.show();
```

here is what I get:

```
3
5
hi
3
5
ho
0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 
0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 
0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 


5
4
hi
5
4
ho
0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 
0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 
0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 
0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 
0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 


4.0000 4.0000 4.0000 4.0000 4.0000 
4.0000 4.0000 4.0000 4.0000 4.0000 
4.0000 4.0000 4.0000 4.0000 4.0000 


2.0000 2.0000 2.0000 2.0000 
2.0000 2.0000 2.0000 2.0000 
2.0000 2.0000 2.0000 2.0000 
2.0000 2.0000 2.0000 2.0000 
2.0000 2.0000 2.0000 2.0000 


3
4
hi
3
4
```

So one can see that matrix A and matrix B are initializing successfully because all is printed. But temp matrix is not printed.

Comment: What you're doing wrong is not following the instructions in stackoverflow.com's [help] for creating a [mre], no more than one or two pages long, that everyone else can cut/paste ***exactly as shown***, then compile run ***and reproduce the same problem themselves***, in order to determine what the problem is. The problem can be anywhere, not just in the shown code, which is why a [mre] is required. See [ask] for more information.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake!

Comment: Why `Matrix a = Matrix(3, 5);` instead of `Matrix a(3, 5);`? Where is the definition of `Matrix::increase`?

Comment: Don't know :) But would it change the problem

Comment: It would be great to be able to reproduce it. Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Is this an embedded device like an Arduino? Is it possible that you go out of memory and are not able to resize the matrix?

Comment: yes it is from Arduino

Comment: You should use a try-catch block around the resize and print an error message if it fails. I think it throws `std::bad_alloc`